# Simulate NFC tag on an Android phone

Tags: android, tags, nfc, simulate, android-beam

I am working with NFC in Android. I have done things with NFC tags and Android Beam, but I am wondering if is possible to use a Android Phone like a NFC tag.
One problem about it is that when I put near the two phones, Android Beams starts. Also, I have not found information about how I can simulate an NFC tag.
Is it possible?

PS. Sorry for mi english.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can an Android NFC phone act as an NFC tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138077/can-an-android-nfc-phone-act-as-an-nfc-tag)

Answer (score 2):

This was already discussed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138077/can-an-android-nfc-phone-act-as-an-nfc-tag) and the conclusion is "no" or "with difficulty".

BR
STeN